# Comments on .pro file Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there anyway to comment certain sections of my `.pro` file (Qt project)?

In my case I want to comment specific parts that do not apply to the platform I'm currently targeting.

Found this now: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html.

Comment: starting a line with `#` doesn't work?

Comment: Check the documentations you will find the answer

Comment: For platform-specific sections, you can wrap them in e.g. unix { ... }, win32 { ... } or macx { ... }

Comment: btw if they realy doesn't apply to your current platform, why comment them out?

Answer (score 14):

You can comment lines by using a `#` symbol.

In the `.pro` file, **#** before any line or statement indicates a comment.

Answer (score 4):

you have to place a # at the begin of each line.

Answer (score 1):

I think Silva is looking for something like this in .pro file:

```
if(false) {
    ...
    your block
    ...
}
```

This is the programmatic way to do commenting, and you have control of it. Similar approaches may available for other test functions.

Answer (score 0):

If using QtCreator, highlight the section you wish to comment out, then right click for context menu and select 'Toggle Comment Selection'. This is good for large blocks code to comment out.